# Why initialize an object to empty

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

I am learning windows programming with the help of MSDN.Why would somebody initialize an object like the following?

```
WNDCLASS wc = { };
```

Will this zero all the memory of the object?
Whole source code is following:

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif 

#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    // Register the window class.
    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[]  = L"Sample Window Class";
    WNDCLASS wc = { };

    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    // Create the window.

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,                              // Optional window styles.
        CLASS_NAME,                     // Window class
        L"Learn to Program Windows",    // Window text
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,            // Window style

        // Size and position
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,

        NULL,       // Parent window    
        NULL,       // Menu
        hInstance,  // Instance handle
        NULL        // Additional application data
        );

    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    // Run the message loop.

    MSG msg = { };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

            FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW+1));

            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        }
        return 0;

    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably to take advantage of Automatic Initialization.

**Reference:**

**C++03 Standard 8.5.1 Aggregates**
**Para 7:**

> If there are fewer initializers in the list than there are members in the aggregate, then each member not explicitly initialized shall be **value-initialized** (8.5). 
>   [Example:
>
> ```
>  struct S { int a; char* b; int c; };
>  S ss = { 1, "asdf" };
> ```
>
> initializes `ss.a` with `1`, `ss.b` with `"asdf"`, and `ss.c` with the value of an expression of the form `int()`, that is,`0`. ]

While Value Initialization is defined in,
**C++03 8.5 Initializers**
**Para 5:**

> To **value-initialize** an object of type T means:
>   — if T is a class type (clause 9) with a user-declared constructor (12.1), then the default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible 
>     default constructor);
>   — if T is a non-union class type without a user-declared constructor, then every non-static 
>     data member and base-class component of T is value-initialized;
>   — if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
>   — otherwise, the object is zero-initialized